# PHP: Indirect modification of overloaded property

Tags: php, overloading

I'm facing a problem on PHP 5.3.6, I'm getting the following error:

```
 Indirect modification of overloaded property CI_Session::$form_certs has no effect
```

I read about it and found an ugly solution to an old PHP 5.2.x bug from 2007 [here](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/131-Overloading-arrays-in-PHP-5.2.0.html).

But in my case it's not the `__get()` method causing the error but the `__set()` method.

My code looks like this:

```
class CI_Session{
    __set($name,$val){
       return $_SESSION[$name] = $val; 
    }
}
```

And the line causing the error:

```
$this->session->form_cert['foo'] = 'bar'; //$this->session is an instance of CI_Session
```

I have tried explicitly setting `$this->session->form_cert = array();` before doing the above but the problem persists.

I also tested this on PHP 5.3.3 and had the same results.

What can I do besides using this old workaround (that screws up another 500+ lines of code I have already written)? (Is this the same bug? Why would it still exist in 5.3.6?)

Comment: It is not a bug, it rather a php array implementation limit. All what you can do here without that workaround code is write $this->session->form_cert = array('foo' => 'bar'); But I guess this solution isn't acceptable for you.

Comment: Is there a `__get` method in `CI_Session`?

Comment: Yes, there is a `__get()` method, doing basically the same thing the other way around (returning the specified key from the `$_SESSION` array)